# SQLite3 How to handle column index out of range

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

Whenever I want to insert a type object (define below) in the database I get "error 25 : column index out of range".
Which means that the value I try to bind doesn't fit in the query right?

```sql
CREATE TABLE color (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    label TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS object (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    label TEXT NOT NULL,
    color_id INTEGER,
    position_x REAL,
    position_y REAL,
    position_z REAL,
    distance REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY(color_id) REFERENCES color(id)
);

-- few insert to populate color
INSERT INTO color(id,label) VALUES (1,'Black');
INSERT INTO color(id,label) VALUES (2,'White');
INSERT INTO color(id,label) VALUES (3,'Red');
INSERT INTO color(id,label) VALUES (4,'Lime');
INSERT INTO color(id,label) VALUES (5,'Blue');
INSERT INTO color(id,label) VALUES (6,'Yellow');
```

I tried putting the query using the CLI interface and this worked.

```sql
insert into object (label,color_id,position_x,position_y,position_z,distance) values ("can",2,0.2,0.2,0.2,1.2);
```

I checked the number of fields, the name of variables, my database is open when my class is created and close on destruction. And last colorIndex is an int that I retrieve from a function I already use to insert other element in a different table. I also printed the values and they are correct.

I guess I m missing something here. I can't see where else can be my mistake.

```cpp
        typedef struct Object{
            std::string label;
            std::string color;
            float pos_x;
            float pos_y;
            float pos_z;
            float distance;
        } Object;
    
        int VisionModel::getColorByLabel(std::string sColor){
            int colorId;
            query = "SELECT id FROM color WHERE label = (?)";
            pStmt = nullptr;
            int rc;
            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,query.c_str(), -1, &pStmt, NULL);
            if (rc != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "prepare getColorByLabel didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return colorId;
            }

            if (sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, sColor.c_str(), -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "bind color label didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return colorId;
            }

            while ( (rc = sqlite3_step(pStmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {                                              
                colorId = sqlite3_column_int(pStmt, 0);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
            return colorId;
        }

        void VisionModel::createObject(Object object){
            query = "INSERT INTO object (label,color_id,position_x,position_y,position_z,distance) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pStmt = nullptr;
            int rc;
            // get the index for given color
            int colorIndex = -1;
            if (!object.color.empty() && object.color != "0"){
                colorIndex = getColorByLabel(object.color); 
            }
            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,query.c_str(), -1, &pStmt, NULL);
            if (rc != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "prepare createObject didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return ;
            }

            if (sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, object.label.c_str(), -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "bind object label didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return ;
            }

         
            if (colorIndex != -1){
                rc = sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt, 2, colorIndex);
                if ( rc != SQLITE_OK){
                    std::cout << "bind object color index didn t went through" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << std::to_string(colorIndex) << std::endl;
                    manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                    return ;
                }
            }

            if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 3, object.pos_x) != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "bind object pos x didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return ;
            }
            if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 4, object.pos_y) != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "bind person object y didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return ;
            }
            if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 5, object.pos_z) != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "bind person object z didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return ;
            }
            if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 6, object.distance) != SQLITE_OK){
                std::cout << "bind person object distance didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return ;
            }

            if ((rc = sqlite3_step(pStmt)) != SQLITE_DONE) {                                              /* 2 */
                std::cout << "step didn t went through" << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return ;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
        }
```

Here is a minimal reproductible version of the code that you can copy paste and compile. Don't forget to create the database with the query above first.

compile : `g++ -o main main.cpp -lsqlite3`

code :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>

typedef struct Object
{
    std::string label;
    std::string color;
    float pos_x;
    float pos_y;
    float pos_z;
    float distance;
} Object;

class VisionModel
{
private:
    sqlite3 *db;
    const char *zErrMsg = 0;
    std::string query;
    sqlite3_stmt *pStmt; 
public:

    VisionModel()  
    {
        connect();
    }

    ~VisionModel()
    {
        close();
    }

    void connect()
    {
        int rc;

        std::string db_file_path("./database.db");

        rc = sqlite3_open(db_file_path.c_str(), &db);
        if (rc)
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't open database" << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "SQL code error : " << sqlite3_extended_errcode(db) << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    };

    void manageSQLiteErrors(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt)
    {
        std::cerr << "SQL error : " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "SQL code error : " << sqlite3_extended_errcode(db) << std::endl;
        sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
    }

    void close()
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
    };
    int getColorByLabel(std::string sColor)
    {
        int colorId;
        query = "SELECT id FROM color WHERE label = (?)";
        pStmt = nullptr;
        int rc;
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &pStmt, NULL);
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "prepare getColorByLabel didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return colorId;
        }

        if (sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, sColor.c_str(), -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "bind color label didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return colorId;
        }

        while ((rc = sqlite3_step(pStmt)) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            colorId = sqlite3_column_int(pStmt, 0);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
        return colorId;
    }

    void createObject(Object object)
    {
        query = "INSERT INTO object (label,color_id,position_x,position_y,position_z,distance) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pStmt = nullptr;
        int rc;
        // get the index for given color
        int colorIndex = -1;
        if (!object.color.empty() && object.color != "0")
        {
            colorIndex = getColorByLabel(object.color);
        }
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &pStmt, NULL);
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "prepare createObject didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return;
        }

        if (sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, object.label.c_str(), -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "bind object label didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return;
        }

        if (colorIndex != -1)
        {
            rc = sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt, 2, colorIndex);
            if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                std::cout << "bind object color index didn t went through" << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::to_string(colorIndex) << std::endl;
                manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 3, object.pos_x) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "bind object pos x didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return;
        }
        if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 4, object.pos_y) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "bind person object y didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return;
        }
        if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 5, object.pos_z) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "bind person object z didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return;
        }
        if (sqlite3_bind_double(pStmt, 6, object.distance) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "bind person object distance didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return;
        }

        if ((rc = sqlite3_step(pStmt)) != SQLITE_DONE)
        { /* 2 */
            std::cout << "step didn t went through" << std::endl;
            manageSQLiteErrors(pStmt);
            return;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Object obj = {"apple", "Blue", 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 2.0};
    VisionModel vm;
    vm.createObject(obj);
}
```

Comment: What seems to be missing is a [mre].

Comment: Is it better now ? I m not sure what else could I put in this. I have my request,  an example of insert, the structure of my input.
All the if that makes it complicated to read are just error handling. Should I remove it ?

Comment: Which part of a [mre]'s explanation: "Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself" is unclear. So, how can anyone else can reproduce your problem, on their own computer, please explain? Anyone should be able to cut/paste what's in your question, ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. Until anyone can do that, it's not a [mre]. The SQL is a good start. Now, what about a complete C++ program, complete with a `main()`?

Comment: Which function is returning an error?

Comment: ```sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt, 2, colorIndex);
```
It is this chunk that doesn't go threw

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just created a minimal reproducible example as asked. Thanks again for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used your debugger to show the value of `query` here, the problem becomes very easy to see:

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &pStmt, NULL);
```

You will discover that this `query` is not really the `INSERT` statement that you think it is.

This is because just a few lines earlier:

```
colorIndex = getColorByLabel(object.color);
```

And this ends up clobbering the `query` variable, setting it to a "SELECT" with just one `?` placeholder.

You can use this as a golden opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, which makes solving these Scooby-Doo mysteries simple. Try to use the shown program in your debugger, ***exactly as is***, setting a breakpoint at the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` line in `createObject`, and then inspecting what's in the `query`, and having your own "Eureka!" moment.